# Cant register Facebook Developer

Tags: facebook

I needed to register as a facebook developer to use facebook sdk. facebook asked me for phone number to do it. I entered my mobile number in order to receive the confrimation code. I tried the code but it was wrong. I got this error from facebook: "There was an error verifiying your contact information".

I tried a view times but i got always the same code and nothing happend.

How can i register now?